# How to pass parameters to function in the same component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, parameter-passing

I'm trying to create nodes with different names dynamically. I've tried to so by passing values to the function in the same component. However, on the console, the parameter passed still shows as undefined.

```
  const ElmArchitecture = ({name}) => {
    console.log(name);
  var engine = new DiagramEngine();
  engine.installDefaultFactories();

  var model = new DiagramModel();
  var node1 = new DefaultNodeModel(name, "rgb(0,192,255)");
  let port1 = node1.addOutPort(" ");
  node1.setPosition(100, 100);

  var node2 = new DefaultNodeModel("view", "rgb(192,255,0)");
  let port2 = node2.addInPort("Model");
  node2.setPosition(400, 100);

  let link1 = port1.link(port2);
  link1.addLabel("Label1");

  var node3 = new DefaultNodeModel("Child", "rgb(0,192,255)");
  let port3 = node3.addOutPort(" ");
  node3.setPosition(50, 50);

  var node4 = new DefaultNodeModel("Parent", "rgb(192,255,0)");
  let port4 = node4.addInPort("Child");
  node4.setPosition(150, 10);

  let link2 = port3.link(port4);
  link2.addLabel("Label2");

  model.addAll(node1, node2, link1, node3, node4, link2);

  engine.setDiagramModel(model);

  return <DiagramWidget className="srd-demo-canvas" diagramEngine={engine} />;
};

class SecondPage extends Component {
  render() 
  { 
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="secondPage_second_div">
          <ElmArchitecture>Model</ElmArchitecture>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SecondPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the name parameter to ElmArchitecture component.

```
class SecondPage extends Component {
  render() 
  { 
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="secondPage_second_div">
          <ElmArchitecture name={"Model"}></ElmArchitecture>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to pass anything to your component

Try this

```
<ElmArchitecture name={"Name"}>Model</ElmArchitecture>
```

This will make name available in your child component `ElmArchitecture` like this

```
props.name
// > Name
```

And you can get it in your child component `ElmArchitecture` like you did (through destructuring)

```
const ElmArchitecture = ({name}) => {...
```